# CSS absolute positioning issue in IE and Firefox but not Chrome - Wordpress Template

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I modified a WordPress responsive theme to include my client's logo within the header. When adding this in, I've knocked around a bunch of other divs, and I'm slowly piecing it back together.

The main challenge I'm having is with the

```
#header-menu
```

ID  ( http://ubcf2.garyspagnoli.com ) not rendering properly on certain browsers. It stays fixed to the right side, and no longer acts responsive to the design.

Here is the CSS I implemented (and also check out the site) to see how I positioned this over the logo image -

```
#header-menu {
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Any advice on how to fix this? Can I not absolute positioning in a responsive design?

Comment: do you want `#header-menu` over `h1#site-title`?

Comment: Yes. This is correct. I've done this with the current code, but it's giving me issues in Firefox and IE.

Comment: well there's some serious positioning problems! lol I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Looks to me like floating the `hgroup` that contains the `h1` headline and `nav` menu is to blame here – inside that you have your image with an intrinsic width of 1184 pixels, and `max-width:100%` – but since the parent `hgroup` has no explicit width set and is allowed to flow out of its container, that messes the whole thing up. So remove that float, and the whole thing will look a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

remove your `h1#site-title`

```
#header-menu{
    background-image:url('http://ubcf2.garyspagnoli.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/UBCF-v1.jpg');
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#header-menu>li{
    float:right;
}
#header-menu>li a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
}
#header-menu>div{
   float:clear;
}
```

add a div after your last list item. You may need to reverse your list items. Also try and remove any unnecessary positionings.